# What's wrong with the following Plot in Manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I try to show the convolution of a step function and a triangle function is smooth with the following code:

```
Manipulate[f0 = UnitBox[p - t0]; f1 = 2 UnitTriangle[t0]; 
 f2 = Convolve[f0, f1, t0, t1];
 Plot[{f0, f1, f2} /. {t0 -> x, t1 -> x}, {x, -3, 3}], 
{{p, -2}, Locator}]
```

It should be something like this:

[image: The original PIC]

But after have a click to locate the Locator, it seems Mathematica have plot some "non-necessary" curves (I have marked by red cross):

[image: After cilck]

How the get the right plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you expect, because a [`Locator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locator.html) is clearly a point `{x,y}`. Even if you initialize it with `-2`, after the first click, it is converted to a point, thus the behavior.

```
Manipulate[f0 = UnitBox[First[p] - t0]; f1 = 2 UnitTriangle[t0];
 f2 = Convolve[f0, f1, t0, t1];
 Plot[{f0, f1, f2} /. {t0 -> x, t1 -> x}, {x, -3, 3}], {{p, {-2, 0}}, 
  Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I see, it is exactly as you point out, it is a point!!!